# Changing uploader for Flutter/Dart on same machine

Tags: dart, flutter

I created package and uploaded via an account. i.e. `uploader@outlook.com`. I did not want to upload via this email address so I did:

```
pub uploader add new_uploader@outlook.com
```

Then I did

```
pub uploader remove uploader@outlook.com
```

The package displays correctly `new_uploader@outlook.com` now but I cannot figure out when I need to do a publish to use the `new_uploader@outlook.com` account. When I try:

```
flutter packages pub publish
```

It gives me this error:

> UnauthorizedAccess: Unauthorized user: uploader@outlook.com is not allowed to upload versions to package flutter_platform_widgets. 
>   pub finished with exit code 1

How do I tell flutter cli or the pub cli to use `new_uploader@outlook.com` and not `uploader@outlook.com`.

Both are google authorised accounts.

Also trying to do:

```
 pub uploader add uploader@outlook.com
```

Gives an Unauthorized error.

Note: email addresses are not real, just for the purpose of the post

Comment: I would recommend opening an issue on the pub repo https://github.com/dart-lang/pub

Answer (score 4):

I did find the following as suggested by https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/14055

Delete the credential file:

```
 .pub_cache/credentials.json
```

After doing this it asked for reauthentication which I used the new email address. I successfully uploaded the package with that email address.

Problem solved for me